# $[\kappa(x) : k]_{sep}=\#\operatorname{Hom}_k(A, \Omega)$ ? ( $A$ is a finite $k$-local algebra and $\kappa(x)$ is its residue field )

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $ k \subseteq \Omega$ be a field extension where $\Omega$ is algebraically  closed. Let $A$ be a finite $k$-local algebra with the residue field $\kappa(x)$ ( So it is artinian ).

Then $[\kappa(x) : k]_{sep}=\#\operatorname{Hom}_k(A, \Omega)$ ( $[\kappa(x) : k]_{sep}$ is the separable degree ) ?

I know that for a finite field extension $L/K$, $[L: K]_{sep} = \#\operatorname{Hom}_K(L , \bar{K}).$ (c.f. https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2021fa/LectureNotes4.pdf ) Can we use this? Can anyone helps?